# Oracle Grid Infrastructure 12c Release 2 installation ASM Disk Group Candidates are empty

Tags: oracle, grid, oracle12c

I am installing Oracle Grid Infrastructure for a Standalone Server (Oracle Restart) per this [article](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/install/gridinstss/gridinstss.htm#t2s1) and cannot see any disks/candidate disks: http://prntscr.com/fgl12s

I have tried different mask: http://prntscr.com/fgl1bu

```
[root@Rhino ~]# oracleasm configure -i
Configuring the Oracle ASM library driver.

This will configure the on-boot properties of the Oracle ASM library
driver.  The following questions will determine whether the driver is
loaded on boot and what permissions it will have.  The current values
will be shown in brackets ('[]').  Hitting <ENTER> without typing an
answer will keep that current value.  Ctrl-C will abort.

Default user to own the driver interface [oracle]:
Default group to own the driver interface [dba]:
Scan for Oracle ASM disks on boot (y/n) [y]:
Writing Oracle ASM library driver configuration: done
```

`[root@Rhino ~]# oracleasm init` doesn't produce any output

```
[root@Rhino ~]# oracleasm scandisks
Reloading disk partitions: done
Cleaning any stale ASM disks...
Scanning system for ASM disks...

[root@Rhino ~]# oracleasm status
Checking if ASM is loaded: yes
Checking if /dev/oracleasm is mounted: yes

[root@Rhino ~]# oracleasm listdisks
DATA1
DATA2
DATA3
DATA4

[root@Rhino ~]#  /usr/sbin/oracleasm querydisk DATA1
Disk "DATA1" is a valid ASM disk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appeared discovery paths should be: `/dev/oracleasm/disks/*`